# Selenium dont finds child elements

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath, appium

I have an issues with finding direct childs of element in android app. I have following sctructure:
[image]
I want to find all direct childs in ListView. Following to xpath syntax they should be found in the next way:

List childs = listView.findElements(By.xpath("./*")); But I have got empty list. I checked this xpath in browser and it works perfectly.

Also I tried:

1)".//*" - returns all childs but with parent element(ListView)

2)"./child::*" - returns empty list.

3)listView.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.TextView"); - returns desired childs, but I want to find child elements regardless of their class.

Should I use smth else instead xpath or I just use wrong xpathes?

Comment: I think the correct one is `child::*` without the `./` you've got there. Also `child::node()` may work. refer to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: I just tried both (listView.findElements(By.xpath("child::*"));)  and them return empty list